# Dynamically generate return type based on parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function that receives an array of strings and returns an object whose keys are the strings and every value is `undefined`:

```
function getInitialCharacteristics(names: string[]): ??? {
  return names.reduce((obj, name) => ({ ...obj, [name]: undefined }), {});
}
```

Example usage:

```
const result = getInitialCharacteristics(["hello", "world"]);
// result == { hello: undefined, world: undefined }
```

Now I wonder how I can define the proper return value for `getInitialCharacteristics` using TypeScript. I'd have to use generics or somehow dynamically generate that type. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to call this function with constants or string literals, typescript can help you get a stricter type for the return object

```
function getInitialCharacteristics<T extends string>(names: T[]): Record<T, undefined>
function getInitialCharacteristics(names: string[]): Record<string, undefined> {
  return names.reduce((obj, name) => ({ ...obj, [name]: undefined }), {});
}

const result = getInitialCharacteristics(["hello", "world"]);
result.hello //ok
result.world //ok
result.helloo //err
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQJJhrAhgGwGEALXAJ12lTJgGdYJaAeAFUVQA8pUwATWxPRphkAPgAUYXAFtUtAFyIWAbQC6ASkUAlVBDhlerADSJwvVMBhhUvUQChQkWAhTosOGARLlK3GvRhGSRk5RSErZDVNRB09AyZwkRMzCysbUUQAbztERDJ0EDIkKVlaADp83hAIVHFxOAAjACsTEtR1RABeDPFMxDKBxpbEZTbVRRTLa15EAF91E0z5gG47Wbs7PTB6PLkQfCgu10xsPCJSCip-BlpxZQAiYlR8fDh7k3uAd318XnuNVb5Wj7KBlJ4vOCIAD0ULgAGs7ECQWVvmRftDYQikQcwc9XpCYdQyEA)

Comment: @Lukas I tend to favor predefined mapped types, that type could be written as `type Characteristics<K extends string> = Partial<Record<K, any>>` but this is a matter of taste

Comment: Sorry I just deleted my comment because it was a stupid idea, but I dealing with the `{}` in reduce not matching the Record, currently I am using a typecast because from the "outside" I don't want to mark the properties as nullable