# Dynamically generate return type based on array parameter of objects in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to define a TypeScript definition like the following:

```js
interface Config {
    fieldName: string
}
function foo<T extends Config>(arr: T[]): Record<T['fieldName'], undefined>
function foo(arr: Config[]): Record<string, undefined> {
  const obj = {}
  _.forEach(arr, entry => {
    obj[entry.fieldName] = undefined
  })

  return obj
}

const result = foo([{fieldName: 'bar'}])
result.baz // This should error since the array argument did not contain an object with a fieldName of "baz".
```

The above code is highly inspried by  [Dynamically generate return type based on parameter in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883166/dynamically-generate-return-type-based-on-parameter-in-typescript) which is almost exactly what I want to do except my parameter is an array of objects instead of an array of strings.

The problem is that the type of `result` is `Record<string, undefined>` when I want it to be `Record<'bar', undefined>`. I'm pretty sure my return definition of `Record<T['fieldName'], undefined>` is not right (since `T` is an array of `Config`-like objects) but I can't figure out how to specify that correctly with the generic type.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Linter will never "catch" strict type, because `const obj = {}` is implicitly of type `any`. So, you will get a runtime error `Property 'baz' does not exist on type Record<'bar', undefined>` but you cannot get it strictly after `.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answers here have identified the issue: TypeScript will tend to widen the inferred type of a string literal value from its [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) (like `"bar"`) to `string`.  There are different ways to tell the compiler not to do this widening, some of which are not covered by the other answers.

One way is for the caller of `foo()` to annotate or assert the type of `"bar"` as `"bar"` and not `string`.  For example:

```
const annotatedBar: "bar" = "bar";
const resultAnnotated = foo([{ fieldName: annotatedBar }]);
resultAnnotated.baz; // error as desired

const resultAssertedBar = foo([{ fieldName: "bar" as "bar" }]);
resultAssertedBar.baz; // error as desired
```

TypeScript 3.4 introduced [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#const-assertions), a way for the caller of `foo()` to ask for a narrower type without having to explicitly write the type out:

```
const resultConstAsserted = foo([{ fieldName: 'bar' } as const]);
resultConstAsserted.baz; // error as desired
```

---

But all of those require the *caller* of `foo()` to call it in a different way to get the desired non-widening behavior.  Ideally `foo()`'s *type signature* would be altered in some way so that the desired non-widening behavior just happens automatically when called normally.

Well, the good news is you *can* do that; the bad news is that the notation for doing this is weird:

```
declare function foo<
    S extends string, // added type parameter
    T extends { fieldName: S },
    >(arr: T[]): Record<T['fieldName'], undefined>;
```

First let's make sure that it works:

```
const result = foo([{ fieldName: "bar" }]);
result.baz; // error as desired
```

Looks good.  The normal call to `foo()` now outputs `Record<"bar", undefined>`.

If that seems like magic, I agree.  It's *almost* explainable by saying that adding a new type parameter `S extends string` hints to the compiler that it should infer a type narrower than just `string`, and therefore `T extends {fieldName: S}` will tend to be inferred as a field name with a string literal `fieldName`.   And while `T` is indeed inferred as `{fieldName: "bar"}`, the `S` type parameter is inferred as *`string` and not `"bar"`*.  Who knows.

I would love to be able to answer this question with a more obvious or simple way to alter the type signature; maybe something like `function foo<T extends { filename: const string}>(...)`.  In fact a while ago I filed [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) to suggest this; so far not much has happened.  If you think it would be useful you might want to go there and give it a .

---

Finally, @kaya3 makes an astute observation: the type signature of `foo()` really doesn't seem to care about `T` itself; the only thing it does with `T` is look up the `fieldName` value.  If this is true for your use case, you can simplify the `foo()` signature considerably by only caring about `S`:

```
declare function foo<S extends string>(arr: { fieldName: S }[]): Record<S, undefined>;

const result = foo([{ fieldName: "bar" }]);
result.baz; // error as desired
```

And this doesn't even seem like that much black magic, because `S` is inferred as `"bar"`.

---

Okay, hope this helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQ2Ac2QbwFgAoZM5bCAGwBMA5OAWwgC5kBnMKUHEgXxI0ICKnCgoYAVxAIwwTBXToAPABVkEAB6QQNdmkzYcAPgAUYqG1UBtALoBKNgCVh6KDTXWA5JVoNmXrYANMjSQtggEDTGANwkJAiYnMhwICDoYHCQNABCYmwARABGYgXIALzIxaVxxIkgyeLsklRgAIJpGVlRFYroptb4FMDU9EysKZ2Z2XlQyHwOtU0t7VPdNAB0JQBeMcgA9PsaUFBuKfpC7MDiNPF1SWDIy61t7OzQM2K9MEoDQ75jZiFEpQMpwfTVUHzRYkZ7tN4fKKzLZwXYHI7QU5zcHIS7XKJ3eqNCDNVoYBrw95QbLfX6DYajfwTLwgrzzc7IIlgGHEOHkzivKnZFFow7HLEcvE3O4gcbsAAOiBQADElABlXCysCScSoAAWqRwPSIxBI5FxwlE4go0lk8hAfWUZvN5DVGm0EF0+k43BAOBCYrgNCENGQYAAnvKUIqoONIFBnS7kOotDo9AQGX5xmw3XwgomXWYLFY7I5kC5Eu5PD4RlmAsFQroIBEorE7uauU8SStaf16QCmcDStD7LVzWK3cBvVweCF1FOCAPs1UQQUYgJSOQ4SK9mLMWccVKCabiBvkCRZcwFUrkBrGPKqMBKDRVegNTgtTqIPrDcb2+QhBEMQJFtOQFB+FQC3NN1U09dMfR4AsixONh-lrQEJlzUtnFcKs1RCMJm1AVtagLTs4V7P5MwwocoQWUcC23HZdwxE4DwuEl8VuE8+CAA)

Comment: Excellent! I actually tried the `S extends string` way first but couldn't get it to work; I don't remember what I did differently to your solution, though.

Comment: Yeah, I don't blame you for not finding it; it's weird.

Comment: Is there any practical difference between this signature and `function foo<S extends string>(arr: { fieldName: S }[]): Record<S, undefined>`?

Comment: No, not really (unless `T` matters in the real use case, but the example code doesn't show such a dependency). That's a good suggestion and you should feel free to mention that in your answer (or if you want I'll add it to mine)

Comment: I don't think it fits in my answer, so feel free to use it in yours.

Comment: This is excellent, and surprising (to me), Typescript continues to surprise.

Comment: Hey @jcalz, do you have a link explaining that `Record<S, undefined>`? I didn't get that...

Comment: What part is confusing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the object literal `{fieldName: 'bar'}` is inferred as type `{fieldName: string}`, not the more specific type `{fieldName: 'bar'}`. Anything you do with the object, such as putting it into an array and passing it to a generic function, will not be able to recover the string literal type `'bar'` from its type, because that string literal isn't part of its type in the first place.

One way around this is to construct your object with a generic function instead of an object literal, so that the stricter `fieldName` property type can be preserved:

```js
function makeObject<T>(s: T): { fieldName: T } {
    return { fieldName: s };
}

const result = foo([ makeObject('bar') ])

// type error: Property 'baz' does not exist on type Record<'bar', undefined>
result.baz
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Answer (score 0):

I would propose something like so

```
interface Config {
    fieldName: string;
}
function foo<T extends Config>(arr: ReadonlyArray<T>) {
    const obj = {} as { [P in T["fieldName"]]: undefined };
    arr.forEach(entry => {
        obj[entry.fieldName] = undefined;
    });

    return obj;
}

const result = foo([{ fieldName: "bar" }, { fieldName: "yo" }] as const);
result.baz; // error
```

The key bit is to use your array as const to prevent any widening of the type so that the generic foo infers the correct T, in more detail, the type of T is now

```
{ readonly fieldName: "bar" } | { readonly fieldName: "yo" }
```

so that T["fieldName"] is

```
 "bar" | "yo"
```

etc.